# Fultter project build on VSCode but failed on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code, app-store

I have recently created flutter project including firebase which build and runs perfectly on VS Code and IOS simulator. But after I tried the same project opening 'iOS' folder in XCode and configuring 'Signing & Capabilities', build was failed and throws following errors.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My questions are

1. Build and running through VS code and IOS simulator is enough?
2. Will this be an issue when app deploying in 'App Store'?

Comment: Normally flutter needs to build and archive app in Xcode to deploy to App Store. But in new flutter version it says build can be produced from terminal command, haven't personally tried it yet. See this link https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder? You can try that from _Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder_

Comment: @beria I tried but not worked